# Insert multiple rows in single query and update existing

Tags: mysql, insert-update

Is it possible to insert multiple rows in single query but in the same time check if record exist and update existing record?

I have to avoid REPLACE INTO because my table have primary and unique keys.

Comment: Yes, Look up *on duplicate key*

Comment: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: "I have to avoid REPLACE INTO because my table have primary and unique keys." Er, all tables have PRIMARY KEYs. It's pretty much the definition of an RDBMS table!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where to put ON DUPLICATE KEY in my query?

```
insert into mytable (A, B C) values 
('a','b',1),
('c','d',2),
('e','f',3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE A = VALUES(A), B = VALUES(B), C = VALUES(C)
```

This is solution:

```
insert into mytable (A, B C) values 
('a','b',1),
('c','d',2),
('e','f',3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE A = VALUES(A), B = VALUES(B), C = VALUES(C)
```

Thanks to all!